# Navigation Drawer Activity? Remove placeholders?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Before proceeding, i have found alot of documentation from google searching.. The topics I have discovered though was aimed at the more experienced developers, I for one found it hard to adapt exampled code into my own scenario (as a novice!).. Even the google documentation is lacking(?) on information on how to proceed

In the android studio Navigation drawer activity.. It's populated with a few design templates, though coming fully fledged with a placeholder blank fragments.. Though, the complication encountered is on these lines:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
```

Then the next function in this main class:

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    //Testing Strings/Lables/Menu
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.HomeFrag);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.ChatFrag);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.CampaignFrag);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.AccSettingsFrag);
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is how do i proceed forward? I'm looking to replace the placeholder fragment(s) with my own Activities/Fragments under the MainActivity.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position` given to you in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` to show the correct `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (position) {
    case 0:
      fragment = new HomeFragment();
      break;
    case 1:
      fragment = new ChatFragment();
      break;
    case 2:
      fragment = new CampaignFragment();
      break;
    case 3:
      fragment = new AccSettingsFragment();
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position " + position);
  }
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
}
```

Using whatever method/fragments you need in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the response! & I take it as these are initializing a new class on each press, This would require `new > Activity > Blank Activity With Fragment`? Which would create a new .java and .xml files?

Comment: & I further take it, you mean `switch (position)` as opposed to `switch (number)`??

Comment: No, in this case you have a single activity for your Navigation Drawer, you're just replacing the fragment being shown so if anything you'd want `new > Fragment > Fragment (blank)` and yes, updated to be `switch(position)`

Comment: Thank for you for the response! I'm following now.. I'm a little disapointed that the google docs fail to mention an alternative based on the template for the navigation drawer, is this due to Android Studio being recently changed to public release? Also, on the initialization I'm getting an Incompatible type Error, Required is: `android.support.v4.app.fragment`, Found is `com.testApps.testing.HomeFrag`?

Comment: Make sure each of your fragments extend the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class.

Comment: I have done this: `tools:context="android.support.v4.app.Fragment"` yet it still throws this error

Comment: `com.testApps.testing.HomeFrag` is a Java class - that's what needs to be updated.

Comment: Ah, Got it now. There is another error stating that `fragment` might not be initalized. So i've defaulted to: `Fragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment()` temporarily

Comment: Yeah, you can use a `default` case in your `switch` in cases to please the compiler. I've updated the question to throw an exception in those cases (which should never happen because you control the number of items).

Comment: Just updated the code to what you've provided `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)` fragment may not have been initialized. Error still apparent. also, getting a message stating that I should implement `onfragmentinteractionlistener`. Which is present, other questions/posts have indicated using `new HomeFrag().NewInstance("Param1","Param2");`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68450/discussion-between-ianhanniballake-and-daryl-gill).